# two non dynamic bodies collsion not possible

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have two physics bodies both are non-dynamic (static)

when i touch the object it move along with my touch and when the two objects collide

-BeginContact: is not calling

here are my two objects

```
         SKSpriteNode *bg= [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"wood.png"];
         bg.position = CGPointMake(60, self.frame.size.height/2);
         bg.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path2];
         bg.name = @"wood";
         bg.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
         bg.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
         [self addChild:bg];





         SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"wood2.png"];
         sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width-40, self.frame.size.height/2+40);
         sprite.name =  @"woods";
         sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPath:path];
         sprite.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
         sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
         [self addChild:sprite];
```

here i will move the one object and i try to touch the other they are not colliding

please help me out 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an object's bitMask properties. These properties include:

```
self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask
self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask
self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask
```

Then you need have code to check for contact.

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
    if (collision == (CNPhysicsCategoryObjectA | CNPhysicsCategoryObjectB))
    {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

You also have the `- (void)didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact` method to check if a contact has ended.

Read the Sprite Kit Programming Guide section on Simulating Physics. The section on [Working with Collisions and Contacts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html) will explain it in more detail.

> Working with Collisions and Contacts
>
> Sooner or later, two bodies are going to try to occupy the same space. It is up to you to decide how your game responds. Sprite Kit uses two kinds of interactions between physics bodies:
>
> A contact is used when you need to know that two bodies are touching each other. In most cases, you use contacts when you need to make gameplay changes when a collision occurs.
>
> A collision is used to prevent two objects from interpenetrating each other. When one body strikes another body, Sprite Kit automatically computes the results of the collision and applies impulse to the bodies in the collision.
>
> Your game configures the physics bodies in the scene to determine when collisions should occur and when interactions between physics bodies require additional game logic to be performed. Limiting these interactions is not only important for defining your game’s logic, it is also necessary in order to get good performance from Sprite Kit. Sprite Kit uses two mechanisms to limit the number of interactions in each frame:
>
> Edge-based physics bodies never interact with other edge-based bodies. This means that even if you move edge-based bodies by repositioning the nodes, the physics bodies never collide or contact each other.
>
> Every physics body is categorized. Categories are defined by your app; each scene can have up to 32 categories. When you configure a physics body, you define which categories it belongs to and which categories of bodies it wants to interact with. Contacts and collisions are specified separately.